# iptables - forwarding traffic from internal network to external network not working

Tags: linux, iptables, ping

I'm running almalinux 8 and I've 3 network interfaces attached to my VM

```
`[root@puppetmaster ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:d1:2f:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s3
       valid_lft 80482sec preferred_lft 80482sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fed1:2f93/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:e4:53:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.128.2/24 brd 192.168.128.255 scope global noprefixroute enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fee4:538a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp0s9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:c5:47:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.10/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s9
       valid_lft 69570sec preferred_lft 69570sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fec5:47fa/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`
```

Now I want to forward all network traffic from `enp0s8` to `enp0s9`. so I tried to do it via iptables. for that I ran below commands

```
[root@puppetmaster ~]# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
[root@puppetmaster ~]# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface enp0s9 -j MASQUERADE
root@puppetmaster ~]# iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface enp0s8 -j ACCEPT
```

here is the output of iptables

```
[root@puppetmaster ~]# iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
[root@puppetmaster ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

but still I can't ping

thanks

I should be able to ping from internal network

-------- EDIT ------------------

I setup other vm and added default route

```
[root@websrv ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:d1:2f:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:f0:16:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.128.10/24 brd 192.168.128.255 scope global noprefixroute enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fef0:16bd/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp0s9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:ca:35:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[root@websrv ~]# ip route
default via 192.168.128.2 dev enp0s8
192.168.128.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.128.10 metric 101
```

However when I try to ping it get back with response to dns request but not icmp request

```
[root@websrv ~]# ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.192.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2074ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. On nat server default route was for other interface from the interface that I was defining in iptables nat table. I've removed that default route from list and I was able to ping to the server. Other way was to keep the routing table as it is and change the interface on the iptables. both the way I was able to solve it.